# Are there any rules regarding the position of the Wicket Keeper?

Tags: rules, cricket

After watching an IPL match I had this doubt. In the match the wicket keeper stood close to the 30 yard circle and the umpire Simon Tauffel came up to the wicket keeper and asked him to move forward.

My question is:

**Are there any rules regarding the position of wicket keeper? If yes what are they?**

Comment: Is it permissible to stand in a wider position as a wicket keeper and allow a long stop behind the stumps to act as a fielder behind the stumps ?

Comment: @user6271 Yes, but as Peter Eisentraut's answer explains, under Law 40 one would forfeit the right to wear wicket-keeper's equipment if one was not able to act as a wicket-keeper in that position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the relevant [law](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-40-the-wicket-keeper,66,AR.html):

> If by his actions and positioning it is apparent to the umpires that he will not be able to discharge his duties as a wicket-keeper, he shall forfeit this right [to gloves and external leg guards] and also the right to be recognised as a wicket-keeper for the purposes of [other laws].

I haven't seen the incident, but the umpire evidently opined that standing at the 30-yard circle is not a suitable position to discharge the duties as a wicket-keeper.  Which is probably reasonable, because the fielding side was probably trying to have an extra "normal" fielder to stop runs rather than someone tending to the wicket.  So the umpire advised the player to either come closer to a position suitable for a wicket-keeper, or he would have to take off his gloves and leg guards.  The alternative would be that the umpire does not advise the fielder and immediately calls him for illegal fielding, but that's not how things are typically done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are rules regarding the position of the wicket keeper check this link http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/cricket/rules_and_equipment/4180026.stm

The incident that ur talking about is Dinesh Karthick stood at the end of 30 yards circle with one glove on. i don't think there any one glove rule. But a wicket keeper can have gloves only if he stands within the 30 yards circle.

Comment: that does nt say anything about the position of wicket keeper, Its about powerplay field position

Comment: It is written there wicket keeper must stay inside 30 yard circle,

Comment: `Keeper can wear gloves only if he stays inside the 30 yard cirlce`

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the Laws for your claim about the 30 yard circle?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any rule related to the distance of a wicket-keeper from the stumps but he has to stay inside the 30 yard circle. Also, if he is standing just behind the wickets, no part of his body should be ahead of the stumps towards the batsman's side. Otherwise, it is a no ball.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't think there's any rule about this one.
I have seen cricket matches with Shoaib Akhtar at his prime, and the keeper used to stand a good couple of yards behind the 30 yard circle.
Other instances include Jeffery Dujon, when he used to keep wickets for WI in the times of Curtley Ambrose and the like.